# HTTP Error 403.7 when using Server Certificates on SSL

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, iis, ssl

I'm trying to secure our webservices by means of using server certificates. For testing, I created a self signed certificate on IIS management console and configured the site to use the certificate.
On IIS I created the HTTPS binding, and configured it to use the certificate. Enabled SSL on the virtual path of my webservices and set it to *require* client certificates.

Right click on the certificate, exported it along with a password to the test client's filesystem.

I used the following code to invoke the webservice using the certificate as client certificate:

```
SSLServiceReference.DataAccessService lService = new SSLServiceReference.DataAccessService();
X509Certificate2 lCert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\Dev06\Documents\TestSamsung2Cert.pfx", "qwerty");
lService.ClientCertificates.Add(lCert);
lService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
DataSet lSet = lService.GetSites();
```

But upon invoke of GetSites() I am receiving a 403.7 http error.
What am I doing wrong? My intention is to require clients consuming the webservice to present this certificate so only they can invoke it.

IIS 7

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, you don't *need* the server and client to be using the same certificate, in fact it probably would be a better idea to use a unique certificate for each.  IIS on the server side will be happy with just about any client certificate (unless you configure it otherwise or write code to examine the certificate and approve/deny based on certain fields).  That said, I don't think this is the cause of the problem you're experiencing.  It is likely due to the client side not really being able to access the certificate or its private key.

You may have better luck if you "install" the pfx certificate to the client machine's certificate store.  Then you need to "export" it again as a .cer file *and* configure access to the private key for the account running your client application (i.e. Network Service).

See this here, if you follow these steps (e.g. install the PFX to the local machine store of the client and configure access to its private key) you should be in business:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649203.aspx

I'm not sure what IIS version you're using but the later ones actually make this process a bit easier.  Also I've found that when things really act strange, that examining the initial SSL handshake traffic with a tool like WireShark can be helpful.  It can help you figure out if the problem is on the client or the server.  In this case it looks like the client side.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and get back to you. If both client and server have different certificates (which, IIRC, is sufficient for a SSL communication), how can you verify that only certain certificates can access a site/service? I was told that sharing a certificate was what was to be done to achieve this.

Comment: There are a few ways:  1) Client certificates that are not signed by a trusted CA are denied by default.  You could limit the trusted CAs on the server (I don't recommend this though)  2)  You can write code in your application that will examine the certificate and make a decision yay or nay for access (this is what I've always done).  or 3) IIS has a way to map client certificates to user accounts (I've not used this).

Comment: I see you're using IIS7, not sure what OS but in the newer ones, you can give access to the private key of the cert via the Certificate MMC (User Interface).  In the past you had to use the command line tool winhttpcertcfg mentioned in the link I posted.